# Different event handler on the same element with different parent

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

Let's say I've got 2 lists:

1. things to complete (lets say 5 items)
2. completed one (0 items)

```html
<div id="todo">
  <div class="item">
    <div>item 1
      <button>done?</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>item 1
      <button>done?</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  ....
</div>
<!-- TODO END -->

<div id="done">
</div>
```

When I click on button it should move the item to div with id 'done', and that works fine.

But let's say I've made a mistake and want this item to show up in 'todo' again.

I can't make it work:

```js
var done = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for (var i = 0; i < done.length; i++) {
  var parent = done[i].parentElement;
  var gparent = parent.parentElement;
  if (gparent.getAttribute('id') === 'done') {
    done[i].addEventListener('click', itemDone, false);
  } else if (gparent.getAttribute('id') === 'todo') {
    done[i].addEventListener('click', itemNotDone, false);
  }
}
```

Above is the code with my event listeners.

And here are bits from two functions:

This one works and moves item from TODO to DONE.

```js
function itemDone() {
  // take the button parent
  var parent = this.parentElement;

  // some other stuff here - styling changes mostly

  // move challenge to done
  var done = document.getElementById('done');
  done.appendChild(parent);
}
```

But I can't move from DONE to TODO.

```js
function itemNotDone() {
  // take the button parent
  var parent = this.parentElement;

  // some other stuff here - styling changes mostly

  // move challenge to done
  var notdone = document.getElementById('todo');
  notdone.appendChild(parent);
}
```

Any idea what should I change to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

change the `itemDone` method to

```
function itemDone() {
  var done = document.getElementById('done');
  elClone = el.cloneNode(true); //clone the node so that events are not carried forward
  this.parentNode.replaceChild(elClone, el);
  done.appendChild(this.parentNode);
  this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
  elClone.addEventListener( "click", itemNotDone, false );//assign the event to go back to todo
}
```

Comment: With this change the only thing that worked was change of styles to the element, it didn't even moved to done list, while earlier it worked.

I don't know if I explained it well - When clicking on button the item should move to DONE list. While in DONE list clicking the same button should move item to TODO list.

Comment: @haRacz sorry for the delay, can you please share a fiddle of your problem http://jsfiddle.net?